# Spring RestTemplate custom mapping

Tags: java, html, json, spring, rest

I'm new to Spring and following along the example at http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest.
I noticed they haven't mapped all the JSON elements from http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware so I wanted to extend the example a little. For this example, I wanted to add "likes" and "were_here_count", like so in Page.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Page {

    private String name;
    private String about;
    private String phone;
    private String website;
    private int were_here_count;
    private int likes;

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getAbout() {return about;}
    public String getPhone() {return phone;}
    public String getWebsite() {return website;} 
    public int getVisitCount() {return were_here_count;}
    public int getLikes() {return likes;}
}
```

and making these changes in Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();                 
        Page page = restTemplate.getForObject("http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware", Page.class);
        System.out.println("Name:    " + page.getName());
        System.out.println("About:   " + page.getAbout());
        System.out.println("Phone:   " + page.getPhone());
        System.out.println("Website: " + page.getWebsite());
        System.out.println("Visit count: " + page.getVisitCount());
        System.out.println("Likes: " + page.getLikes());
    }
}
```

I was thinking that the mapping was done by element name, and that worked for "likes", but didn't for "were_here_count". Output:

```
Name:    Pivotal
About:   Pivotal is enabling the creation of modern software applications that leverage big & fast data – on a single, cloud independent platform.
Phone:   (650) 286-8012
Website: http://www.pivotal.io
Visit count: 0
Likes: 1175
```

were_here_count is currently at 60. I'm guessing the default converter didn't like the underscore in the variable name. So I used the overloaded version of getForObject, providing my own mapping, like so:

```
package hello;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>(3);
        variables.put("name", "name");
        variables.put("about", "about");
        variables.put("phone", "phone");
        variables.put("website", "website");
        variables.put("were_here_count", "were_here_count");
        variables.put("likes", "likes");

        Page page = restTemplate.getForObject("http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware", Page.class, variables);
        System.out.println("Name:    " + page.getName());
        System.out.println("About:   " + page.getAbout());
        System.out.println("Phone:   " + page.getPhone());
        System.out.println("Website: " + page.getWebsite());
        System.out.println("Visit count: " + page.getVisitCount());
        System.out.println("Likes: " + page.getLikes());
    }
}
```

But all to no avail. I've seen a few examples regarding custom JSON converters here but didn't understand them well - plus, this is a much simpler example, could I not get this done with a simple String-String mapping of variable names?

Anyone know how to do this and willing to show me how to build a custom converter and what the necessary steps are? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7):

Try adding some of [Jackson's annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) to your `Page` class to help with the deserialization of the JSON.  You should be able to tell Jackson (which will handle serialization/deserialization of JSON in Spring by default), what attributes in the response JSON map to your POJO attributes.:

```
public class Page {
    ...
    @JsonProperty("were_here_count") 
    private int wereHereCount;
    ...
}
```

Another option, if you are not sure what attributes are being returned, is to just map the JSON to a `Map`:

```
Map<String,Object> map = restTemplate.getForObject("http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware", Map.class);
for (Map.Entry entry: response.entrySet()){
    // do stuff...
}
```

Sometime this is the easier way to do custom object mapping when the response JSON is convoluted or just doesn't deserialize easily.

Comment: Thanks really this solution was easier and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

What does your setter for Page looks like? It works for me with this setter:

```
public void setWere_here_count(int were_here_count) {
    this.were_here_count = were_here_count;
}
```